# Mocktrofit resolving gradle dependency

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependency-management, android-testing

I'm trying to integrate mocktrofit on android (https://github.com/vokal/Mocktrofit) to mock retrofit API calls and I'm having issues trying to resolve the dependencies.

This is what I get when trying to resolve the dependency:

```
    Error:Could not find io.vokal.gradle:mocktrofit-processor:0.1.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/io/vokal/gradle/mocktrofit-processor/0.1.0/mocktrofit-processor-0.1.0.pom
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/io/vokal/gradle/mocktrofit-processor/0.1.0/mocktrofit-processor-0.1.0.jar
```

Has anybody used mocktrofit in Android Studio?

Thanks!

Comment: please add your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 1):

I think that to make the mockup of the services you have to use this module:

[Retrofit Mock](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit-mock)

Consequently build.gradle should look like:

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-mock:2.0.0-beta3'
```

}

Some examples at this url:

[Some examples](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit)